# GraphQL: Sorted Query Based on User Attribute

Tags: sorting, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I just implemented Pagination in my iOS Application using AWS Amplify, DynamoDB, and GraphQL. What I would like to do is query users based on their score ranked from highest to lowest. In order to do that, I would need to sort my query when making the call. How can I make the sorted query based on a user's score?

Below is my User Table

```
type User @model @key(fields: ["username"]) {
  name: String
  email: String!
  username: String!
  dateOfBirth: String
  university: String!
  phoneNumber: String!
  biography: String
  score: Int!
  deviceToken: String
  endpointArn: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for indexes.

In terms of how to implement that data access pattern, when you use the `@key` directive, Amplify creates a Global Secondary Index for you. In this case, since you're just interested in high scores, you can create another GSI on the score field by adding the following directive to your User model:

`@key(name: "UsersByScore", fields: ["username","score"], queryField: "UsersByScore")`

Then, with a specified limit `n` and sort direction, use the UsersByScore query generated by Amplify to query for the `n` users with the highest (or lowest) scores.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can the OP give this a try as it should achieve what they want.

Comment: Hi @mparis I'm active on the Amplify CLI and SDK Github issues pages. Anyone with Amplify queries should check those issue pages too (or someone should make it a project to port over Github resolved issues to StackOverflow answers). https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues

Comment: @jkeys, I think there are problems with your aswer: first of all, fields should be ["username", "score"].
Second, using the `@key` you suggested amplify will raise an error: ```Invalid @key "UsersByScore". You may not create a @key where the first field in 'fields' is the same as that of the primary @key unless the primary @key has multiple 'fields'. You cannot have a local secondary index without a sort key in the primary index.```

Comment: @Valerio you were right on about the syntax error. But I didn't know the GraphQL transformer doesn't support adding a sort field to a new index.

Comment: @mparis is this a known limitation of the GQL transformer?

Comment: @jkeys I started a issue in amplify-cli repo to address this specifi case. I stumbled upon your answer because I was searching for this exact problem.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2643

Comment: @Valerio got it, I'll watch that issue.